# How to display a label when tableView is empty

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I want to display a label when the tableView is empty. **I have tried the other solutions proposed on this page but none have worked for me.** I want to say something like "Press the add button to create a new class". My TableviewController is:

```
#import "ClasesTableViewController.h"
#import "ClasesTableViewCell.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ClasesTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ClasesTableViewController

@synthesize clases;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context  = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Clases"]; /*Cambia el titulo del navigation controller*/

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}]; /*Cambia el color de las letras del navigation controller bar del menu principal*/

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:62/255.0f green:152/255.0f blue:73/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

    self.TableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init]; /*Esta linea hace que en la tabla solo aparezcan el numero de filas que tienes establecidas, es decir, que las vacias no aparezcan*/

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; /*Cambia el color del boton de la izquierda*/

    UIBarButtonItem *infoBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info_white48@2x.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self  action:@selector(infoAction)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: _AddBarButton, infoBarButtonItem, nil];


}


-(void)infoAction
{
    NSInteger clasesDadas = clases.count;

    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nClases dadas: %d", (int)clasesDadas];


    UIAlertView *alertatiempo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Información" message:inStr delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertatiempo show];

}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateClase"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedClase = [clases objectAtIndex:[[self.TableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        ClasesViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.clase = selectedClase;
        destViewController.numberOfClasses = clases.count;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Clases"];
    clases = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return clases.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    /*UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];*/
    ClasesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    //Configure the cell
    NSManagedObject *clase = [clases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.dateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", /*countString,*/ [clase valueForKey:@"date"]/*, [clase valueForKey:@"date"]*/]];
    [cell.timeLabel setText:[clase valueForKey:@"time"]];
    [cell.paidLabel setText:[clase valueForKey:@"paid"]];
    cell.paidImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@" "];

    if ([cell.paidLabel.text isEqualToString:@"No"] || [cell.paidLabel.text isEqualToString:@"no"]) {
        cell.paidLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    if ([cell.paidLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Si"] || [cell.paidLabel.text isEqualToString:@"si"]) {
        cell.paidLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        cell.paidImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"paid_green@2x.png"];
    }

    return cell;

}



 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
     return YES;

 }


 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         // Delete the row from the data source
         [context deleteObject:[clases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

         //invoke the "save" method to commit the change
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![context save:&error]) {
              NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
             return;
         }

         //Remove clase from table view
         [clases removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [self.TableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

     }
 }

@end
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Explain what you tried that got closest and what it does wrong

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use other custom UITableViewCell to show the empty state.

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{
    return clases.count>0?clases.count:1;  //Return 1 if clases array is empty 
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  if(clases.count==0 && indexPath.row == 0)
  {
    //return a custom cell  with the label "Press the add button to create a new class"
  }
  else
  {
    //return an instance of ClasesTableViewCell as you was doing in your code which represents one class
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a great library called [DNZEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet) that does this basically for free.

All you need to do is assign your table view controller as delegate and data source of the empty data set:

```
self.tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self;
self.tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self;
```

and then just return whatever message you'd like to display in

```
- (NSAttributedString *)titleForEmptyDataSet:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

There's a lot of additional capabilities, check out their Github webpage for more documentation. They also allow you to display image, subtitle, button, completely custom view etc.

Just remember to remove yourself from the delegate/datasource in `dealloc` method!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I used was check if no results for cells, use uitableview cell at index path 1 (or 2) to display a msg.

in cellforrowatindexpath: 
     if no results
          if indexpath.row equals 2
               Cell.titlelable.text equals "Press the + button"

This is the most simple way of doing it for me, but you can also use custom cells as other members said below.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make UILabel and give text as you want and where you get web service response then check if you have data to display then make tableview.backgroundView = nil else put your label as a backgroundView so tableview.backgroundView = yourLabel

You can set any view as per your requirement.you also can put button.